# Jenkins not starting any more EC2 slaves when using labels

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins v1.564 with the [Amazon EC2 Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) and set-up 2x AMIs. The first AMI has the label **small** and the second AMI has the label **large**. Both AMIs have the *Usage* setting set to **Utilize this node as much as possible**.

Now, I have created 2x jobs. The first job has *Restrict where this project can be run* set to **small**. The second job, similarly, set to **large**.

So then I trigger a build of the first job. No slaves were previously running, so the plugin fires up a **small** slave. I then trigger a build of the second job, and it waits endlessly for the slave with the message *All nodes of label `large' are offline*.

I would have expected the plugin to fire up a **large** node since no nodes of that label are running. Clearly I'm misunderstanding something. I have gone over the plugin documentation but clearly I'm not getting it.

Any feedback or pointers to documentation that explains this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found there's an *Instance Cap* setting in *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System* under *Advanced* for the EC2 module, which limits how many instances can be launched by the plug-in at any one time. It was set to 2. Still odd as I only had one instance running and it wasn't starting another one (so maybe the limit is "less than" ). Anyway, increasing the cap to a higher number made the instance fire up.

Comment: I need to run my regression tests on remote ec2 instance. For now, I set up the ec2 plug in, specified the AMI ID, added labels for that AMI in Cloud section of Jenkins configuration. Actually what I need is to: launch a ec2 instance in pre-steps, run application-run script on it and shut down the instance in post steps. So, how can I force Jenkins to launch specified slave only when a particular build starts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are the two machine configurations using the same image?  If so, you're probably running into this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19845

The EC2 plugin counts the number of instances based on

Comment: Actually I found out what the issue was. See my answer.

Comment: That was the issue for me. From one of the comments on the ticket: "it appears the plugin counts all instances in the EC2 account, not just the ones launched by Jenkins. In other words, if you have other instances in your EC2 account, they count, as well."